# What kind of model is the most appropriate to assess the effects of forest succession on soil?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model

My data set comprises of 12 plots (10 forest plots in different successional ages + 1 coffee + 1 pasture (age = 0). In each plot, we assessed many different soil quality indicators, whereas we had 3 soil samples (values) per plot. So, in total we have 36 soil samples (12*3=36). What kind of model would be more appropriate to assess the effects of age and canopy openness on soil quality indicators?

Comment: Random effect is needed to incorporate the correlation among 3 soil samples from the same plot. No description on "soil quality indicators", so cannot say what model is suitable. Also what is "canopy openness"?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments !! Soil indicators are quantitative, such as nutrient content, water holding capacity and carbon of the microbial biomass. Canopy oppeness is a measure from 1 to 100 that indicates the oppeness of he canopy. The closer to 100, the more open (less tree canopy). I want to know how soil quality changes along succession-age ( and what variables change the most)

Comment: Then you can fit mixed linear model.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the tip! 
Any suggestion on how a general script can be written in R? Or any suggestion on where can I find more information on how to build a script for this?

thank you,

Comment: Mixed linear model is common in software, so you can work on your available software. About theory, you can go to linear model (fixed effect only) and then read something about how to add the random effect to incorporate the not independent situation.

Comment: Is that model correct: canopy_model= lmer (canopy_open ~ log(age) + (1|age), data = data)

Comment: No. The random part should be (1|plot). In your dataset, should have a variable plot to indicate the sample comes from which plot.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But as each plot have a different age, I guess it would be the same result, right? The weird thing is that I have got the same values for the Intercept and coefficient for the effect of age both for the linear model and for the mixed linear model.  Would that be correct?

Comment: It is possible. Check the standard error or variance of estimated intercept and coefficient of age. I think SE or Var should be different.